# Is Telegram bot token secure: does SSL encrypt the requested URL?

Tags: ssl, https, sniffing

Is Telegram bot token secure as long as it's being use in url for each api method call? Is there a risk that someone steal Telegram token in the way to Telegram servers ?

Or in other words:
Does SSL encrypt the url itself ?

Comment: yes, ssl encrypts everything about the request, including the headers, which includes the url. that's not specific to telegram. that's just how https works.

Comment: The requested resource (not full URL) *is part of* the HTTP request payload itself, which might start as `GET /foo?bar=secret` (and other headers follow). HTTPS encrypts the entire HTTP request and response. However there are places when the target HTTPS URL can surface *before* it is put in the payload, such as in a browser history. The URL can also surface relatively frequently in server logs.

Comment: (And don't forget about all the broken SSL configurations floating about.. if the server negotiates one of these then - *boom!* - instant not secure. Same applies for running unpatched/vulnerable server versions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an SSL encrypted HTTPS connection, the secure connection between the client/server is established first before any data is exchanged.

Once the secure connection is fully established, the client sends an HTTP GET request to the server. This GET request contains the URI as well as any query parameters. In the event of a POST, the POST data is contained within the body of the request.

In your case, the token included as a querystring parameter in the URI would be securely encrypted.